# Getting double instead of the task in C# Task, why?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have the interface:

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<double> GetData(int id);
}
```

And I need to use this interface in my class:

```
//_svc is a Type of IService

public async void Doit()
{
    Task<double> task = await _svc.GetData(id);
}
```

And when I do it, it says that it can't convert type double into *Task<double>*
Why is this double instead of the task? The interface clearly specifies that this is a task and here I need to get the task, not the value.

Comment: it is because Task<double> returns double. GetData will get data in background and return to main thread result as a dobule

Comment: read more about `await` keyword

Comment: Maybe I should change the way I call it? to Task<double> t = Task.Run<double>(()=> _svc.GetData(id));  ?

Comment: @Sasha, so what should I do? Change it from task<double> to task?

Comment: @J.Doe I would use a result that I would get from Task. I mean I would work with double. Not sure why you need Task, but try answer..

Comment: I need a task because then, I want to add task.ContinueWith where I could process different scenarios

Comment: @J.Doe. You do not neet Task then. With await it will wait for a result, and only then go further.

Comment: I don't think await is the best option because I want to check the status of the task: failed, canceled, successful. So if I want it this way, should I use Task.Run?

Answer (score 4):

If you need the task to handle it yourself, then remove the `await` that handles it for you.

Comment: You mean, I shoud use: Task<double> task = _svc.GetData(id);

Comment: No Task.Run is necessary?

Comment: The `Task.Run` is probably inside the method that is returning the task.

Comment: so you think this would be the correct way of using the interface's method? : Task<double> t = Task.Run<double>(()=> _svc.GetData(id));

Comment: No that looks horrible. Please don't take it personally, but you don't seem to know what you are doing. I suggest you read a good book or tutorial on this. Then decide what you want. It will either be `double d = await _svc.GetData(id);` or it will be `Task<double> t = _svc.GetData(id);`. But I cannot tell you what you want. Only you know that.

Answer (score 1):

It is not an answer, but i hope it will help you to understand Tasks a little bit more. For example you have interface with method:

```
  System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> FindNameAsync(string computerName);
```

When you call a method from interface, it will be something like this:

```
var result = await _scv.FindNameAsync(name); //The program will not go to next line, until it becomes result
```

When it will get result it will go further. And result you can pass to next methods

**EDIT**
If you want to get statuses you can make little modifications:

```
 System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> FindNameAsync(string computerName);
```

Then you can return true in case of success, in other case - false.
With a little modification you can pass object to method as parameter and save values that you need in it. Or you can return dictionary or turple, and not bool. Little example:
Your method can be like here:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task<bool> FindNameAsync(SomeClass obj);
```

And you can handle it so:

```
SomeClass test = new SomeClass();
if(await _scv.FindNameAsync(test))
{
//code for success result
}else
{
//if error happened handle here
}
```

Comment: this is not what I need. I need to process the statuses of the task. So I need to call the method in the task and check the statuses and only then get the result with continueWith

Comment: @J.Doe: You should not need to do that. You should ***never*** use `ContinueWith`.

Answer (score 0):

> The interface clearly specifies that this is a task and here I need to get the task, not the value.

When an interface declares a method that returns a Task or Task<T> the name of the method should - by convention - also end with "Async": https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443

Such a method is expected to be implemented as an async method that returns an object of type T if the return type is declared as Task<T> or nothing at all if the return type is just Task:

```
public interface IService
{
    Task<double> GetDataAsync(int id);
}

public class Service : IService
{
    public async Task<double> GetDataAsync(int id)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        return 1.0;
    }
}
```

You would await such a method:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public async void Doit()
    {
        IService service = new Service();
        double d = await service.GetDataAsync(1);
    }
}
```

Now whether the method actually *is* implemented as an async method is an implementation detail in the concrete implementation of the interface but it doesn't really matter as far as the consumer of the interface is concerned as you can still always await a method that returns Task or Task (provided that the caller method is marked with the async keyword of course).

You would for example be able to await the following non-async implementation of the method the same way:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public Task<double> GetDataAsync(int id)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(1.0);
    }
}
```

So methods that have a return type of Task or Task<T> are meant to be asynchronous and awaited.

You *could* still store an instance of the method's actual return type in a variable "as usual" though:

```
public void Doit()
    {
        IService service = new Service();
        Task<double> task = service.GetDataAsync(1);
    }
```

This would however simply call the asynchronous without waiting for its return value which makes it pretty useless to even call the method in the first place. When calling a - by contract and convention asynchronous - method that returns a Task<double> you are interested in getting the double value back *asynchronously*. You don't really care about the Task object itself if you understand what I mean.

Comment: `You would call such an async method by awaiting it:`  No, you don't *call* a method by awaiting it.  You call it by calling it, `service.GetDataAsync(1)`.  You continue executing the method when the `Task` has finished by awaiting it.  Big difference.